# Autowire current RememberMeServices

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

I'm trying to obtain an instance of current RememberMeServices, but autowire doesn't work. I'm using the default one defined via java configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.rememberMe().tokenRepository(myTokenRepository)
}
```

Class (trying to) autowiring RememberMeServices:

```
public class AuthConfig {
   @Autowired
   private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;
}
```

I get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type...

How to achieve that?

Comment: Make sure it's exposed as a Bean in your context. Post a little more info on how you're configuring this

Comment: @Dovmo I'm not exposing it manually, what i posted is all about _remember me_ I have in my project, and it works through login form default param`remember-me`. I want to use the default one created by spring security (enabled by `http.rememberMe()`). Is there a way? Or should I have to create and expose one by me and pass it to spring security config?